# Error while installing google plugin for Eclipse Mars.2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars, google-plugin-eclipse

I am getting following error while installing google plugin on Eclipse

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_adu_eclipse_jee-mars_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.io,2.4.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.6.3.20160209-1444
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.6.3.20160209-1444
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.6.3.20160209-1444
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple,1.6.3.20160209-1444
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.6.3.20160209-1446
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.6.3.20160209-1446
```

Comment: What version of the plugin are you trying to install?

Comment: Update sites can be a bit flaky sometimes. Try installing the  plug-in again. You might want to see if you can uninstall any pieces of the plugin first, or maybe try Neon.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the Mars update site checked in your *Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites*.  You should have a site pointing to `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars`, with a checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by adding the following repo in the "Available Software Sites":

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

This resolved all of the no repository errors for m2e that you are showing.